# React Project installation always fails at inotify (ELIFECYCLE errno 1)

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-gyp, inotify

I'm trying to install a ReactJs Project on `Ubuntu 19.04`. For some reason, the installation always seems to fail at a certain package called `inotify`.

I'm currently on `node v12.10.0` and `npm v6.10.3`

I've tried several things and even tried to install inotify individually, but nothing seems to have worked. I still have no clue about the reason for this issue.

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "im-lite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://localhost/React-Redux/im-lite/build",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "dev": "0.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "constants": "0.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.6",
    "encoding": "^0.1.12",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-status-monitor": "^1.1.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "floating-label-react": "^0.2.0",
    "formidable": "^1.1.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.2.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "import-export": "^1.0.1",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "ipaddr.js": "^1.3.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "mime": "^2.3.1",
    "next": "^6.1.1",
    "node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "preact": "^8.2.6",
    "preact-compat": "^3.17.0",
    "qs": "^6.4.0",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.5.2",
    "react-adsense": "0.0.5",
    "react-alice-carousel": "^1.13.11",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^1.0.3",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-player": "^1.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.49",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-share": "^2.4.0",
    "react-toolbox": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.7.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-infinite-scroll": "^1.0.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "register": "0.0.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-ip": "^2.0.2",
    "serviceworker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.1",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  }
}
```

This is the stack trace when I execute `sudo npm-install`

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: Way too old

inotify@1.4.6 install /home/vaibhav/Desktop/im/mobile-im-pw/im-lite/node_modules/inotify
node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/vaibhav/Desktop/im/mobile-im-pw/im-lite/node_modules/inotify/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vaibhav/Desktop/im/mobile-im-pw/im-lite/node_modules/inotify
gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.6.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex@7.6.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.0.2 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN next@6.1.2 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN next@6.1.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN serviceworker-webpack-plugin@0.2.3 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2 || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sw-precache-webpack-plugin@0.9.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package babel-core is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package babel-loader is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package css-loader is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package style-loader is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inotify@1.4.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the inotify@1.4.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vaibhav/.npm/_logs/2019-09-23T12_00_42_775Z-debug.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what user executes this action

Comment: superuser, since I'm running 'sudo npm install'

Comment: try and execute the command that gives the error `mkdir ...`

Comment: Make sure you're logged in as an admin user on the server. Normally www-user or similar. Also check owner of the folder, might need to change it first